# GCP/Firebase functions with different scopes in different files

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing GCP functions in a npm repository, here is the structure of my files:

```
$  root .
└── package.json
    └── src
        └── index.ts
        └── functions
            └── fct1.ts
            └── fct2.ts
            └── ...
```

I have multiple function declaration in this `index.ts`, including http functions and event functions.
One of them is serving a NestJs application that needs to initialise NestJs on cold start but since they all are in the same file (`index.ts`) NestJs is in scope for all the functions, including the event functions and other http functions which is delaying the cold start of all of them.

I am currently deploying all the functions in a github action doing `firebase deploy --only functions`.

Is there a way to split the functions declarations in different files?

I found this resource: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions?gen=2nd but I don't really want to create npm repositories for each function that has a different scope. Furthermore, all the functions share resources like models, apis, services, ...

Thanks for the help

Comment: Since you didn't show any code, I just marked duplicates for all sorts of different similar questions.  Also in the future, consider doing a web search before posting, and make an attempt using what you learn there.  Then if that doesn't work, show what doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Also read: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/organize-cloud-functions-for-max-cold-start-performance-and-readability-with-typescript-and-9261ee8450f0

Comment: @DougStevenson I did search but couldn't find a solution. Thanks for the duplicate, I'll have a look, it seems to solve my issue at first sight.